# How does the compiler find the missing return statement?

Tags: java, return, java-11

I have a function to find an element in an array (Binary search). 
I get an error saying that there is a 'missing return statement'. (Commented part)

> **How does the compiler understand that a return statement is missing?**

*How does the compiler find all the execution paths, when only 'if's are used. There is no else-if being implemented*

```
public static int rank(int key, int []a, int lo, int hi)
    {
        if(lo>hi) return -1;
        int mid= lo+(hi-lo)/2;
        if(key<a[mid]) return rank(key,a,lo,mid-1);
        if(key>a[mid]) return rank(key,a,mid+1,hi);
        //else return mid;
    }
```

Comment: Compiler assumes that all if conditions will result in false. So it will come to the end of the method to check if return is mentioned. Just a wild guess.

Comment: You told the compiler you would return an `int`. If all your `if` statements are false, you do not return anything. The compiler is sad. The compiler tells you how sad it is.

Comment: Would it also complain if you remove only the 'else' keyword?

Comment: No. It works fine if I remove the 'else' keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does the compiler find all the execution paths?

It is not very clever about it, it cannot detect branches that can logically never be reached, it just wants all branches to end in a `return`. See this other question for [a case where that is not "clever enough"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50566867/why-if-else-if-else-within-a-loop-in-method-gives-return-statement-missing-w?rq=1).

In your case, it sees that it might be possible that none of the `if` conditions becomes true, so that you fall through to the end of the method and it wants to see a `return` there.

In your case, that reasoning is also correct: As far as I can tell, it might very well fall through all the branches.

Comment: `if(key<a[mid]) return rank(key,a,lo,mid-1);
else if(key>a[mid]) return rank(key,a,mid+1,hi);
else if (key==a[mid]) return mid;`                                                                                                                       So, for this code, the compiler throws error as it detects that all branches may not be reached, even though it does

Comment: If you also add the `==` case, it cannot "logically" fall through all cases, but the compiler will still complain because it does not know that.